# MongoDB: query or aggregate to get different measure data into array in one shot

Tags: mongodb

I have a time series document to store a device's multiple sensor data/1/. In the example, deviceId `A-1` has

```
1)geo info("longitude" : 0.6644560403052914, "latitude" : 0.7165033050936503 ),
2)temperature, ("sensorType" : "temperature","sensorValue" : "14")
3)humidity, ("sensorType" : "humidity", "sensorValue" : "12")
```

The query is based on time range according to createDate, how could I use one query or one aggregation to get three arrays of geo info, temperature and humidity and how to choose index and index type?

/1/data structure

```
{
        "_id" : "7736b113586a4314bfbe036cf6b3e34c",
        "createDate" : ISODate("2016-08-30T16:30:33.007Z"),
        "deviceId" : "A-1",
        "vendorCode" : "01",
        "longitude" : 0.6644560403052914,
        "latitude" : 0.7165033050936503,
         "sensorList" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "1802b2792cac4529b269d5e2c9398e80",
                        "createDate" : ISODate("2016-08-30T16:30:33.007Z"),
                       "sensorType" : "temperature",
                        "sensorId" : 1,
                        "sensorValue" : "14"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "ddbe2d76770c42cfabc8d22d7c732826",
                        "createDate" : ISODate("2016-08-30T16:30:33.007Z"),
                        "sensorType" : "humidity",
                        "sensorId" : 2,
                        "sensorValue" : "12"
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer yet but I wanted to show you where I got.  I'm a little stumped with doing this all within one aggregation.

```
> db.foo.aggregate([
...     // First project out the fields we don't need.  geoInfo only requires latitude and longitude so let's take care of it first.
...     {"$project": {"_id": 0, "geoInfo": {"longitude": "$longitude", "latitude": "$latitude"}, "sensorList": 1}},
...     // Now let's group based on the sensorType, we need to unwind our array first
...     {"$unwind": "$sensorList"},
...     {"$group": {
...         "_id": "$sensorList.sensorType",
...         "value": {"$first": "$sensorList.sensorValue"},
...         "geoInfo": {"$push": "$geoInfo"}
...     }}
... ]);

{ "_id" : "humidity", "value" : "12", "geoInfo" : [ { "longitude" : 0.6644560403052914, "latitude" : 0.7165033050936503 } ] }

{ "_id" : "temperature", "value" : "14", "geoInfo" : [ { "longitude" : 0.6644560403052914, "latitude" : 0.7165033050936503 } ] }
```

Comment: Mongo engineer said it is not recommend to put some business level operation into database level since database resource is limited. So forget this thread.